# passing checkbox parameter to controller not working

Tags: actionsupport, inputcheckboxes

Following your input I made changes but it is still not working.
This is my new code:

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myRec.isPerf}" id="perf">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!togglePerf}" rerender="theBlock">
           <apex:param name="perfId" assignto="{!selectedItemId}" value="{!myRec.Id}"/>
    </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:column> 


public ID selectedItemId {get; set;}

public void togglePerf(){
      Wrapper wrapper = mapIdWrapperItem.get(selectedItemId);
}
```

Please advise...

**Original message:**

I have a column with an apex:inputCheckbox component in it.
On change I want to execute some controller logic which needs to know the value of a parameter on the page.
When the controller method is called I see the parametr is null although I know that in the page it has a value.
Can anyone suggest why this is not working and what is the right way to do this?

This is my VF code

```
<apex:column >
   <apex:facet name="header">Performing</apex:facet>                                            
   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myRec.isPerf}" id="perf">
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!togglePerf}" rerender="theBlock"/>
       <apex:param name="perfId" value="{!myRec.Id}"/>
   </apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:column>
```

Controller code where selId is always null:

```
public void togglePerf(){
    String selId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('perfId');
    ItemWrapper wrapper = mapIdWapperItem.get(selId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well seems to be a basic syntax mistake. We generally wrap the param component inside a parent action component.

Something like

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!togglePerf}" rerender="theBlock">
    <apex:param name="perfId" value="{!myRec.Id}" />
</apex:actionSupport>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:param name="perfId" value="{!myRec.Id}" assignTo="perfId1"/>

and use get the variable through

String selId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('perfId1');
```

Comment: Please add some useful information to your answer.

Comment: In his code i gotta see like he forgot to place assignto attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by the following way:

```
<apex:param name="perfId" value="{!myRec.Id}" assignTo="{!perfId1}"/>
```

and create a similar variable in the controller.

```
String perfId1;
system.debug(perfId1); // this will print the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything I tried failed so I ended taking the action support out and used apex:actionFunction like this:

```
 <apex:actionFunction name="toggleMMcheckboxJS" action="{!toggleMMcheckbox}" id="actionFunc1" status="assign-action-status" rerender="theRelatedCatalogItemsBlock">
        <apex:param name="selectItemId" value=""/> 
        <apex:param name="selectLevel" value=""/> 
        <apex:param name="selectStatus" value=""/>          
    </apex:actionFunction>


<apex:column headerValue="Select">
    <apex:facet name="header">World Class</apex:facet>                                            
    <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="toggleMMcheckboxJS('{!mapIdWithMaturityModelRelatedItem[currentRecord].Id}', 'WC', '{!mapIdWithMaturityModelRelatedItem[currentRecord].isWorldClass}');" 
                                                selected="  {!mapIdWithMaturityModelRelatedItem[currentRecord].isWorldClass}" id="wc"/>                                                    
</apex:column>





public Pagereference toggleMMcheckbox(){
    String selId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectItemId');
    String selMaturityLvl = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectLevel');
    //the current value before change
    Boolean selStatus = Boolean.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectStatus'));

    try{                            

    }   
    catch(Exception e){
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, e);
    }

    return null;                                    
}
```